# SAP COMMERCE Spartacus - documentation for SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

Is there any good and up to date documentation for SSR with Spartacus (1.5) for SAP COMMERCE?

I know this:

- https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/
- https://enable.cx.sap.com/media/SpartacusA+SSR+Deep+Dive+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_6jbx5p6e

But maybe not everything is up to date in this documentation for current Spartacus release 1.5.

What could be wrong or missing if there is at least something generated with SSR but still things like

```
<header class=""><cx-page-layout section="header" class="header"><!----><!----><!----></cx-page-layout><cx-page-layout section="navigation" class="navigation"><!----><!----><!----></cx-page-layout></header>
```

are in DOM that are not rendering without java script?

Comment: I found at least the reason why there was no content rendered in my case: TLS/https certificate was not valid for the OCC backend services. With a vaild certificate the content is rendered with SSR. But the main question for a good documentation how to setup SSR not just only for local testing is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our experience, we are using these sources of information and technical approaches during project implementation:

**Theory**

- https://angular.io/guide/universal (you can feel free to use Angular official documentation as a primary source, cuz Spartacus uses Angular OOTB features to make it works)
- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/
- https://enable.cx.sap.com/tag/tagid/spartacus (SSR related videos)

**Practical approaches**

- You should observe and analyze console output during starting your application in Node.js
- You can use SSR configuration from example Storefront application (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/develop/projects/storefrontapp) like a starting point, cuz OOTB SSR works like a charm